# JAXB in Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I am using JAXb for Marshelling and Unmarshelling a xml in Spring MVC. I am getting following Error:

```
Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/nav/Navigator.isOverriding(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

at line

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(KbDoc.class);
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks like incompatible jar Version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mix of jaxb versions on your classpath. Please make sure that Spring picks the correct jaxb version by removing the version from classpath which is causing the issue.